# Why is pts in PES packet zero for h264?

Tags: h.264, mpeg2-ts

I detect new PES packet in PES demultiplexer searching packet_start_code_prefix (0x000001). When it occurs then I can read PES_packet_length and so I can extract the current PES packet from byte stream. But if it is a H.264 video stream then PES packet's PTS is zero for alternate PES packets? In such case can I assume those two packets are actually one but split accross the PES packets and use the previous PES packet's PTS as the PTS of the packet with zero timestamp?

Answer (score 2):

PTS is optional - so it is not a violation of the specification. If you don't have PTS/DTS than you can derive it from information in the elementary stream. Let's ignore frame re-ordering for the moment than you can assume that the next frame's DTS(1) is DTS(0) + frame length. You can assume one access unit per PES packet.